# How can i parse json object using retrofit 2.3.0

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

Our team decide to use Retrofit2 and I'm doing some initial research on this library but i'am newbie in Retrofit. How to parse the Json below ?

```
    {
    "main": {
    "totalResults": "500",
    "libelleCategory": "Véhilcule",
    "libelleSubCategory": "Mots et Vélos",
    "idCategory": "1",
    "idSubCategory": "3",
    "row": [
       {
            "id": "66888",
            "shortURL": "https://www.testimage.com",
            "title": "Moto - HONDA - 2007",
            "text": "Pan lorem ipsum test test c'est un test",
            "img": "https://www.test.image.com",
           "price": "6 200",
           "datePublish": "05/05/2018",
           "nbPhotos": "3",
           "address": "75001 Paris"
       },
       {
           "id": "66889",
           "shortURL": "https://www.testimage.com",
           "title": "Moto  - 2018",
           "text": "Pan lorem ipsum test test c'est un test",
           "img": "https://www.test.image.com",
           "price": "9 500",
           "datePublish": "05/05/2018",
           "nbPhotos": "5",
           "address": "75001 Paris"
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to write model class for this json (http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and then follow the retrofit call to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initialize the API, you have to add the JSON converter.

My prefered one is Jackson:

1. Add dependency: `com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson`
2. Set the converter for retrofit

   ```
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
   .baseUrl("https://your.domain")
   .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create()) // In real app, you should provide a preconfigured ObjectMapper for better performance
   .build();
   ```

**Edit**

Example:

Create your model just match with your JSON:

```
public class YourResponse {
    private Detail main; // This will match "main": {}

    public static final class Detail {
       private String totalResults; // This will match "totalResults": ...
       private String libelleCategory;
       private String libelleSubCategory;
       ... bla bla....
       ... your getter/setter method....
    }
    ... your getter/setter method....
}
```

Use it in API class:

```
public interface SampleApi {

  @Get("/your/path/to/get")
  Call<YourResponse> getResponse();
}
```

Initialize your API:

```
SampleApi api = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://your.domain")
                    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create()) // In real app, you should provide a preconfigured ObjectMapper for better performance
                    .build()
                    .create(SampleApi.class);
```

Call your API:

```
Response<YourResponse> serverResponse = api.getResponse().execute();
if (serverResponse.isSuccessful()) {
  YourResponse = serverResponse.body();
}
```

Comment: Can you please give more details ? what should I put as the POJO ? 
it will be great if you give me all the details to parse the json above

Thanks you.

Comment: It will be done for you already. You don't have to do anything, the converter will be used when retrofit parse response

Comment: See the full answer above